# Cannot connect to server with Citrix - error: Cannot find file: /opt/Citrix/ICAClient//config/module.ini

Tags: networking, certificates, citrix

I'm trying to run Citrix receiver on Ubuntu. However when trying to connect with a server using citrix receiver I get the following error message:

```
 Cannot find file: (/opt/Citrix/ICAClient//config/module.ini). Please check your installation, or contact your help desk.
```

When installing Citrix I installed the .deb package using:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/icaclientWeb_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb
```

(Additionally I have followed the [standard procedures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) for linking certificates etc.)

And during the installation there was the following error message which seems to be relevant.

```
 No target module.ini found under .. for en_US.UTF-8
 chmod: cannot access '../nls/en.UTF-8/module.ini': No such file or directory
```

It seems that the installation was only partially successful as the icaclient is available but when I open it I get the same error message as I get when trying to connect to a server. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks,

Ubuntu version:

```
 sam@de-hq-pc153:~$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
 Release:   18.04
 Codename:  bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, I was able to install config files based on this forum post:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472880

You need to use --force-all:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all <.deb>
```

After running this command, it listed all of the missing configuration files and then installed them "as you requested". Good luck!